# How to mock a .properties file injected with @PropertySource in @Configuration?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mocking

My application expects to find a configuration file called **MyPojo.json**, 
loaded into **MyPojo** class by **MyService** class:

```java
@Data // (Lombok's) getters and setters
public class MyPojo {
    int foo = 42;
    int bar = 1337;
}
```

It's not a problem if it doesn't exist: in that case, the application will create it with default values.

The path where to read/write **MyPojo.json** is stored in `/src/main/resources/settings.properties`:

```java
the.path=cfg/MyPojo.json
```

which is passed to **MyService** through Spring's `@PropertySource` as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:settings.properties")
public class MyService {

    @Inject
    Environment settings; // "src/main/resources/settings.properties"

    @Bean
    public MyPojo load() throws Exception {
        MyPojo pojo = null;

        // "cfg/MyPojo.json"
        Path path = Paths.get(settings.getProperty("the.path")); 

        if (Files.exists(confFile)){ 
            pojo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(path.toFile(), MyPojo.class);
        } else {    // JSON file is missing, I create it. 
            pojo = new MyPojo();
            Files.createDirectory(path.getParent()); // create "cfg/"
            new ObjectMapper().writeValue(path.toFile(), pojo); // create "cfg/MyPojo.json"
        }

        return pojo;
    }
}
```

Since **MyPojo**'s path is relative, when I run this from a Unit Test

```java
@Test   
public void testCanRunMockProcesses() {

    try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = 
          new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyService.class)){

        MyPojo pojo = ctx.getBean(MyPojo.class);

        String foo = pojo.getFoo();
        ...
        // do assertion
    }       
}
```

the `cfg/MyPojo.json` is created under the ***root*** of my project, which is definitely not what I want.

I would like **MyPojo.json** to be created under my ***target*** folder, 
eg. `/build` in Gradle projects, or `/target` in Maven projects.

To do that, I've created a secondary **settings.properties** under **src/test/resources**, containing

```java
the.path=build/cfg/MyPojo.json
```

and tried to feed it to **MyService** in several ways, without success.
Even if called by the test case, **MyService** is always reading `src/main/resources/settings.properties` instead of `src/test/resources/settings.properties`.

With two `log4j2.xml` resources instead (`src/main/resources/log4j2.xml` and `src/test/resources/log4j2-test.xml`), it worked :/

Can I do the same with a property file injected by Spring with `@PropertySource` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***@TestPropertySource*** annotation for this.

Example:
For single property:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = "property.name=value")
```

For property file

```
@TestPropertySource(
  locations = "classpath:yourproperty.properties")
```

So, you provide path for MyPojo.json like

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = "path=build/cfg/MyPojo.json")
```

Comment: Do i need to write this before class ?

Comment: This annotation will be used on class For e.g @TestPropertySource(properties = "path=build/cfg/MyPojo.json") public class MyTest {...//Your code }